# Return 0 if no record in last two hours, javascript logic

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I want to return average of records for every two hour for a week. I have start and date time stamp, I returned the calculated average. But I have to check if there is no record for 6 hours then have to return 0 for every tow hours in this case.

What I have done looks like this:

```
var average = [];

// db query with start-end 
db.table.find(query_criteria).sort({"date_time": 1}).toArray(function() {

forEach(function() {

// got record

}

// calculated average for tow hours
average.push(/*average for tow hours*/);

res.send( average );

});
```

result looks like

```
average: 2450,
time: "Sun Mar 22 2015 02:00:00",
hour: "2:00"

average: 2780,
time: "Sun Mar 22 2015 04:00:00",
hour: "4:00"

average: 2360,
time: "Sun Mar 22 2015 08:00:00",
hour: "8:00"
```

Note that there is nothing for 6th hour. I want to check if there is no record between two hours then send 0 average.

Please help to make the logic for this check.

```js
/***********************************************************************
 ***********************************************************************
 ** MongoDb
 ** Will scan MongoDb for weekly temperature average graph.
 **
 ** @author     Created by Sajjad
 ** @date       18/03/15
 ** @access     private
 ***********************************************************************
 ***********************************************************************/
var helper = require('../helpers/jsHelper.js');


/**
 * Return average of temp from DB
 * @param      event from service call
 * @return
 */
module.exports.temp_graph_by_week = function (event, resp) {

    // Selecting table from DB in this case "gateway_status"
    var gateway_status = db.collection("gateway_status");

    // This will contain records from DB
    var temp_record = [];

    // This will send average record and other data of device to client side
    var temp_list_data = {};

    //gateway_id & device_id start date and end date from client side
    var gateway_id = parseInt(event.params.gateway_id);
    var device_id = parseInt(event.params.device_id);
    var start_date = parseInt(event.params.start_date);
    var end_date = parseInt(event.params.end_date);

    temp_list_data.device_id = device_id;
    temp_list_data.gateway_id = gateway_id;
    temp_list_data.data = [];

    // query criteria
    var query_criteria;

    if (start_date && end_date != null) {
        query_criteria = { "date_time": { "$gte": start_date, "$lte": end_date},
            "device_id": device_id, "gateway_id": gateway_id };

        // Getting records from DB
        gateway_status.find(query_criteria).sort({"date_time": 1}).toArray(function (err, res_data) {

                if (err) {

//                    resp.send(err);

                } else {

                    // will contain indoor temperature average
                    var temp_average = 0;

                    // will contain set point average
                    var setPoint_average = 0;

                    // sum of indoor temperature
                    var temp_sum = 0;

                    // sum of set point temperature
                    var setPoint_sum = 0;

                    // for graph weekly bases
                    var hours_difference = 120;

                    // Counting the quantity of records
                    var record_count = 0;

                    // Date time of first record
                    var first_time = null;

                    // Time difference of records
                    var time_difference = null;

                    var record_day = '';

                    var record_check = 0;

                    res_data.forEach(function (data) {

                        // Local object
                        var device_record = {};

                        if (data.data != null && data.data.length != null) {
                            var json_data = data.data;

                            // for indoor temp
                            for (var i = 0; i < json_data.length; i++) {
                                if (json_data[i].r == 203) {

                                    //Pass in the data of indoor temp and time
                                    device_record.indoor = json_data[i].v;
                                    device_record.time = data.date_time;

                                }

                                // for set point temp
                                else if (json_data[i].r == 1004) {

                                    //Pass in the data of set point
                                    device_record.setPoint = json_data[i].v;

                                }
                            }
                        }

                        // Start time
                        if (first_time == null) {
                            first_time = new Date(device_record.time);
                        }

                        // Time difference of records
                        time_difference = helper.MinutesBetweenTwoDates(new Date(device_record.time), first_time);

                        // If we have all records of last two hours
                        if (time_difference >= hours_difference) {

                            record_check = 2;
                            if(new Date(device_record.time).getHours() > record_check){
                                console.log(new Date(device_record.time).getHours());
                            }
                            // Date time of first record
                            first_time = new Date(device_record.time);

                            // Calculating average
                            temp_average = Math.round(temp_sum / record_count);
                            setPoint_average = Math.round(setPoint_sum / record_count);


                            var temp_Date = new Date(device_record.time);
                            temp_Date.setMinutes(0);
                            temp_Date.setSeconds(0);
                            temp_Date.setMilliseconds(0);

                            //  console.log(temp_Date,temp_Date.getDay());
                            if (temp_Date.getDay() == 1) {
                                record_day = "Monday";
                            } else if (temp_Date.getDay() == 2) {
                                record_day = "Tuesday";
                            } else if (temp_Date.getDay() == 3) {
                                record_day = "Wednesday";
                            } else if (temp_Date.getDay() == 4) {
                                record_day = "Thursday";
                            } else if (temp_Date.getDay() == 5) {
                                record_day = "Friday";
                            } else if (temp_Date.getDay() == 6) {
                                record_day = "Saturday";
                            } else if (temp_Date.getDay() == 0) {
                                record_day = "Sunday";
                            }

                            // Push average data of month for sending to client side
                            temp_list_data.data.push({"indoor": temp_average,
                                "time": temp_Date.toString(),
                                "day": record_day,
                                "hour": temp_Date.getHours().toString() + ":00",
                                "setPoint": setPoint_average
                            });

                            // Set them for next two hours
                            record_count = 0;
                            temp_sum = 0;
                            setPoint_sum = 0;
                        }
                        else {

                            //keep adding values in sum till two hours are filled
                            temp_sum += device_record.indoor;
                            setPoint_sum += device_record.setPoint;

                            //keep counting records
                            record_count++;
                        }
                    });
                }
                resp.send(temp_list_data);
            }
        );
    }

};
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean "*if there is no record for 6 hours*"? 04:00 and 08:00 are less then 6 hours apart, so why do you still want to put 0 in there?

Comment: I have to return the average 0 to fill the gape of two hours every time when there is no device record. 04:00 and 08:00 presents hours so 04:00 is less then 6 and 08:00 is grater.

Comment: "Please help to make the logic for this check." is not an appropriate question format for stackoverflow. Show your efforts and ask about specific challenges....

Comment: @Manahil: Yes, you seem to want to fill the gaps, like 6 o'clock in your example. But what does this have to do with a 6 hour time span?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what I understand is right then you are looking to fill some time slots with some data, and if there is no data at some of these time slots you want to fill them with 0. You can pre fill time slots with 0 and then refill them with the data arriving from db.

```
//data with record to send
var average_data = [];

//array with time slots
//differ in start date and end date
var array_with_dates = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

// Pre fill time slots with 0
for (var j = 0; j < array_with_dates.length; j++){

    //required JSON
    var data_for_day = {}; 

    data_for_day.day = array_with_dates[i];
    //pre fill with 0
    data_for_day.average = 0;

    //push to the data
    average_data.push(data_for_day);
}

//Now refill them with the data from db
db.table.find(query_criteria).sort({"date_time": 1}).toArray(function(err, record) { 

record.forEach(function() {

// got record
var record_amount = record.amount;
var current_day = record.day;

//find the right pre filled record and update its avg
for (var i = 0; i < average_data.data.length; i++) {
    if (average_data[i].day == current_day) {

        average_data[i].ctr++;
        average_data[i].sum += (device_record.indoor);
        average_data[i].average = Math.round(average_data[i].sum / average_data[i].ctr);
    }
}

res.send(average_data);

});
```